# Изменения в орфографии

Tags: орфография

Вопрос возник после обсуждения написания слова большевистский (большевицкий). Громко об изменениях в написании нигде объявлено не было. Тем не менее Лопатин внес-таки некоторые поправки. Кто знает, какие слова еще изменили свое написание в словаре у господина Лопатина?

Answer (score 7):

@Ларf, Вы сейчас несколько тенденциозны. "В угоду" никто ничего менять не будет, да и самого факта изменений как такового не было.

Формально - ни одно слово написания не изменило. К словарной фиксации надо относиться как к закрепленной возможности, но не императивному требованию, тем более что есть миллион словарей, эти изменения не поддерживающих. Вообще словарь - дело весьма субъективное. Того же Даля, а ныне - Кузнецова критиковали и критикуют нещадно.

А сам проект изменений от возглавляемой Лопатиным Орфографической Комиссии был зарублен на стадии первичного обуждения под улюлюканье далекой от проблемы публики.

В числе предполагаемых изменений там были и весьма трезвые предложения.

По памяти. Предлагалось упорядочить написание НН/Н в причастиях и прилагательных (бесприставочные отглагольные прилагательные и страдательные причастия регулярно писать с одним Н), ввести последовательно Ъ перед всеми корневыми морфами на Е, Ё, Ю, Я после согласной, расширить применение дефиса, упорядочить написание сложных прилагательных, писать жУри, брошУра и парашУт, заЕц, огурцИ, рАзыскной - список не полный. Часть из предложений была отвергнута сразу самой ОК (огурцИ), всерьез не рассматривалась и в окончательный текст проекта не вошла, единичные были де-факто реализованы (Ъ и рАзыскной), остальные можно считать заживо похороненными.

Если интересно, я подниму содержательное и полемику, я тогда следил за ней внимательно. Хотя в основном она свелась к киданию грязью и истерическим крикам о кретинизации пролетариата.

Неожиданно столкнулся со сложностями при поиске в сети самого текста проекта.

Я уже задал вопрос на "Грамоте" о причинах исчезновения из Сети текста проекта. 
Пока могу предложить только кратное изложение.
http://ruslit.ioso.ru/spelling.htm

И примеры полемики.

Вот одно из лопатинских разъяснений:
[Русская орфография: задачи корректировки | magazines.russ.ru](http://magazines.russ.ru/novyi_mi/2001/5/lopatin.html)

А вот один из самых резких отзывов из числа содержательных (филфак МГУ был и остается антилопатинским бастионом):
[Реформа правописания. Обсуждение проекта | philol.msu.ru](http://www.philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/siencework/orthographyproject/)

Но все это - капля в море...

//------------

Мне дали адрес текста проекта изменений:
[РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК. АКТУАЛЬНЫЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ | gramma.ru](http://www.gramma.ru/KOL/?id=4.2)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как же ничего не изменилось  А большевицкий? Я все-таки привыкла относиться к академическим словарям именно как к норме, а не просто как к фиксации.. .Зафиксировать такое можно!

Comment: @Ларf, мне неловко Вам такое говорить, но Вы не поняли. Большеви**ц**кий не отменяет Большеви**стс**кого. А лишь предлагает не считать первый вариант ошибкой. А насчет нормы и её фиксации тут тоже все естественно. Норму надо понимать как возможность, не императив. Вы же не возражаете, что словарями закреплено тв**о**рог и твор**о**г?    
    
Кстати, словарь - не академический. То, что он вышел из стен ИРЯ РАН, еще не делает его таковым. А история названия связана с тем, что бежали впереди паровоза. Делали словарь под *готовящиеся* правила. Им сейчас это ставят в вину, но это обычная практика

Answer (score 2):

Из методических рекомендация 2015 года для экспертов по проверке экзаменационных работ.  Собственно, ответом на вопрос является пункт 5, но и п. 4 по сути, тоже касается изменений в орфографии, только зафиксированных, как мне кажется, еще до ПАС под редакцией Лопатина.

Цитирую:

4)  написания, для которых менялись орфографические рекомендации:

```
бог / Бог

водноспортивный / водно-спортивный

вторая мировая война / Вторая мировая война

деланный / деланый (в знач. неестественный, ненатуральный: делан(н)ая улыбка)

естественно-научный / естественнонаучный

заполдень / за полдень

заполночь / за полночь

зорянка / зарянка (птица)

как-то / как то (перед перечислением, напр.: Острогою бьется крупная рыба,
как(-)то: щуки, сомы, жерехи, судаки.)

лироэпический / лиро-эпический

масленица / Масленица

масс-культура / масскультура

масс-медиа / массмедиа

мелочовка / мелочевка

народнопоэтический / народно-поэтический

народнохозяйственный / народно-хозяйственный

не сегодня-завтра / не сегодня завтра

невзирая на лица / не взирая на лица

непрошеный (прил.)

первобытнообщинный / первобытно-общинный

плащевка / плащовка

плейер / плеер

рождество / Рождество

интернет/Интернет

розыскник / разыскник

розыскной /разыскной

считанный / считаный (в знач. малый по количеству: считан(н)ые минуты)

церковнославянский / церковно-славянский

черно-бурый / чернобурый
```

**5.** **Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации : Утв. Акад. наук СССР, М-вом высш. образования СССР и М-вом просвещения РСФСР. – М. : Учпедгиз, 1956. (А также издания 1957 и 1962 гг.)**

§ 40. В сущ.  мужского и среднего рода в предл. пад. и в сущ. женского рода            на -а (-я) в дат. и предл. пад. ед. ч. пишется в неударяемом положении и только в том случае, если ему предшествует тоже и, например: о гении, о Кии, в «Вии», по реке Бии…

§ 79, п. 14. Примечание 1. Между определяемым словом и стоящим перед ним однословным приложением, которое может быть приравнено по значению к прилагательному, дефис не пишется, напр.: красавец сынишка.

**Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации : полный академический справочник / РАН, Отделение историко-филол. наук, Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова. – М. : Эксмо, 2006. (А также последующие издания.)**

§ 71, п. 2. Немногочисленные сущ. на -ий, -ия с односложной основой имеют в указанных падежах в безударном положении по общему правилу окончание   -е. Перечень таких слов: змий — о зми́е, кий — о ки́е (вариант: о кие́), Кий (легендарный основатель Киева) — о Кие, чий (растение) — о чие, «Вий» — в «Bue», … Бия (река) — по Бие…

```
§ 120. Следующие разряды сущ. и сочетания сущ. пишутся через дефис
```

<…> 
в) сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик…

Список п.4 вызывает некоторые вопросы, например, где логика в написании слов "мелочевка", "плащовка"?

Comment: Прошу прощения за неудачное редактирование. В источнике п. 5 был дан в виде таблицы, но при копировании получился сплошной текст, пришлось разделить на части. П. 120 почему-то выделился именно так, в виде цитаты, пыталась убрать - не получилось. Если кто подскажет, как вставлять таблицу, буду благодарна.

Answer (score 1):

Как хорошо, что «проект изменений от возглавляемой Лопатиным Орфографической Комиссии был зарублен на стадии первичного обсуждения под улюлюканье далекой от проблемы публики». Кстати, привет Вам от этой публики! Потому что «расширение применения дефиса», «регулярное написание Н в отглагольных прилагательных и страдательных причастиях», упорядочение написания сложных прилагательных» - это просто красивые слова, которыми отвлекают наше внимание. В действительности же за всем эти стоит попытка сломать то, что строилось нашими выдающимися учеными в течение длительного времени и что современной наукой до сих пор не изучено и не понято. Потому что ломать - не строить! Потому что не принято задумываться о том, что наше правописание (еще со времен Ломоносова) имеет грамматический характер, и незначительные на вид орфографические изменения могут серьезно затронуть грамматические основы языка. И еще потому, что наша система письма иногда становится гарантом существования языка в целом. Об этом подробно на http://russianorfo.blogspot.ru/ (искать в Гугл) Кстати, там есть материал о написании «большевистский – большевицкий», в разделе «Решаем задачки».

Comment: >Как хорошо, что «проект изменений от возглавляемой Лопатиным Орфографической Комиссии был зарублен на стадии первичного обсуждения под улюлюканье далекой от проблемы публики». Кстати, привет Вам от этой публики!  

Привет давайте, не оставлять же Вас с ним. 
А вот обсуждать с Вами Ваши лингво-политические воззрения - увольте.