# "Народно-хозяйственный" теперь пишется через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

В словаре у Розенталя это слово имеет слитное написание, что вполне понятно: народнохозяйственный план –  план народного хозяйства, прилагательное образовано на основе сочетания с подчинительной связью.

Но на Грамоте.ру обозначено написание через дефис. А вот в словаре под ред. Лопатина "Слитно, раздельно или через дефис" этого слова и вовсе нет (исчезло вместе с народным хозяйством?). Есть только народно-демократический, народно-освободительный и народно-патриотический, но они и раньше писались через дефис.

А вообще слово   "народно-хозяйственный" применяется в современных текстах? И все ли знают, что оно теперь пишется через дефис?

Comment: Ответы  Грамоты на эту тему: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: http://gramota.ru/biblio/research/slovari-norm/pril3/ Можете и здесь прочитать.

Comment: В одном из ответов (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/22325/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b8/49264#49264) цитируются  методические рекомендации 2015 года для экспертов по проверке экзаменационных работ. Там есть оба варианта (народнохозяйственный / народно-хозяйственный)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но ситуация, конечно, огорчает. Написание сложных прилагательных и раньше не всегда  определялось однозначно, варианты при толковании правил были возможны.  Но это слово в сочетании "народнохозяйственный план" однозначно должно писаться слитно,  иначе получается "народный хозяйственный план", что не имеет смысла.  И ответы Грамоты.ру больше похожи на отговорки (традиция написания и т.д.), а фактически всё это ведет к отмене хотя бы каких-то устоявшихся правил и предложению заучивать словарь наизусть.

Comment: А вот ещё история со словом "миллионоголосый", его одно время начали писать с двумя НН, а сейчас в словаре на Грамоте.ру вернулись к прежней форме с одной буквой Н.

Comment: Однако миллиоННолетний (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=214612)

Comment: А здесь миллиоНолетний: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже всё время возмущаюсь, что мы не успеваем за словарями. Теперь вот Словарь РАН Лопатина закрепил народно-хозяйственный, присовокупив его к остальным "народно-...".

Вот объяснения Лопатина:
http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200003501

- Но вернемся к большому «Русскому орфографическому словарю». Нельзя не отметить еще одно принципиальное нововведение. В словаре впервые приведен «Список слов с измененным написанием» – слов, написание которых в данном словаре отличается от написания, предлагавшегося в выходившем прежде академическом «Орфографическом словаре русского языка». Вообще говоря, авторы всех предшествующих (исправленных и дополненных) изданий «Орфографического словаря русского языка» не обходились без некоторого количества подобных изменений, но эти изменения никогда не афишировались, или, говоря по-ученому, не эксплицировались, на них специально не обращалось внимания. Теперь такой список приведен; в него вошло и некоторое количество написаний, измененных уже в последнем из исправленных, 29-м (1991) издании «Орфографического словаря...», – такие, как геолого-разведочный, **народно-хозяйственный**, первобытно-общинный, церковно-славянский, карате, разыскной (кстати, о написании разыскной см. мою и Ю.Н.  Караулова заметку в «Русском языке», №  3/99). В «Русском орфографическом словаре» предлагается писать по-новому, например, мелочовка, плащовка, чаечий (от чайка), попугаичий, полосануть, гиперъядро, плеер, уикенд, форсмажор, перекатиполе, неразлейвода, **честь-честью**, дурак-дураком, человекочас, машинодень, не сегодня завтра; финноугры, финноугорский и финноугроведение; прилагательные **деланый и считаный** (писавшиеся с нн как исключения).

Answer (score 1):

Живо помню разгоревшиеся страсти при появлении первого словаря Букчиной: уау, кошмар, как же ж жить?! А абитуриентов тихо успокаивают университетские преподаватели: тсс, как жили, так и будем. По Розенталю.

Поясню от себя, **держучи сейчас в руках** "Словарь трудностей русского языка. Авторы: Розенталь, Теленкова", но не тот, что в Сети, сомнительного издательства М.: Айрис-пресс, 2003, 3-е изд. ЯКОБЫ. а родной педагогам и мне 1985 года! Издание ЧЕТВЁРТОЕ! (Любопытно, от рождества чего етая айрис отсчёт ведёт, угум.)

[НАРОДНОХОЗЯЙСТВЕННЫЙ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — слитно и никак иначе! Розенталь сказал. А его под сурдинку "исправили" (гады).

Пояснение разноголосицы девического хора - у [Справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285101):

> Возникновение подобных споров доказывает правоту лингвистов, которые
> давно говорят, что правило о слитном/дефисном написании прилагательных
> на основе соотношения основ (подчинение/сочинение) не охватывает все
> сложные случаи и зачастую не помогает решить вопрос о написании слова.
> В современной письменной речи из этого правила уже очень много
> исключений. Еще в 1970-е годы лингвисты предлагали ориентироваться на
> формальный признак: если в первой части сложного слова есть суффикс
> прилагательного или причастия – пишем через дефис
> (естественно-научный), если нет такого суффикса – пишем слитно. Такому
> правилу соответствует написание конно-спортивный, и оно зафиксировано
> в словаре Б. З. Букчиной, Л. П. Калакуцкой «Слитно или раздельно?»
> (см., напр., 6-е изд. М., 1987).
>
> Многие подобные написания закрепились в письменной речи и
> зафиксированы нормативными орфографическими словарями как исключения
> из действующего правила (например, естественно-научный,
> лечебно-физкультурный, авторско-правовой, народно-хозяйственный и мн.
> др.). Но при этом слово конноспортивный дается в современных словарях
> в слитном написании (т. е. в данном случае предлагается
> руководствоваться действующим правилом). См.: Русский орфографический
> словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд.,
> испр. и доп. – М., 2012.

Тут и Валгина - глава моей (Полигафический ин-т, ныне то акадэмия, то универ, то обратно, но до института уже не опустились) кафедры русского языка переметнулась в стан врагов неподменённого ещё Розенталя, и некая [С. В. Друговейко-Должанская](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=1.208), с теоретизаторством:

> Если ранее в качестве критерия, определяющего тип написания, выступал
> семантико-синтаксический принцип (частное проявление
> лексико-морфологического принципа), требующий учитывать характер
> отношения основ, составляющих сложное слово, то теперь авторы
> реформаторского проекта русской орфографии предлагают заменить его
> принципом формально-грамматическим, т. е. при выборе написания,
> например, сложного прилагательного опираться на фактор
> наличия/отсутствия суффикса в основе первого компонента сложного
> слова.
>
> Рекомендуется писать через дефис сложные прилагательные, имеющие в
> первом компоненте основу относительного прилагательного с суффиксом, а
> также основы на -ик-, -лог-, -граф- (соотносительные с прилагательными
> на -ический), напр.: народно-хозяйственный, северно-русский,
> западно-сибирский, центрально-азиатский, водно-спортивный,
> бессрочно-отпускной, первобытно-общинный, церковно-славянский,
> авторско-правовой, химико-технологический.
>
> При отсутствии суффикса прилагательных в первом компоненте писать
> сложные прилагательные слитно, напр.: нефтегазовый, буровзрывной,
> звукобуквенный, приходорасходный, товаропассажирский.
>
> Таким образом, меняется принцип написания сложных прилагательных,
> последняя часть которых может употребляться в качестве
> самостоятельного слова: семантико-синтаксический принцип (характер
> отношения основ, составляющих сложное слово) заменяется
> формально-грамматическим.

А университетские педагоги продолжают нашёптывать: живём по Розенталю.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Попробую разобраться в этой теме чуть позже, сейчас пока нет времени. Вообще-то интересно почитать то, что было  написано так давно.